# Hide selected option in Mat-Select

Tags: angular, select, angular-material

I`m wondering if I could in a select of angular material 2 hide the selected option. So I have this right now:

```html
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-select placeholder="{{ 'NAVBAR.LANG' | translate }}"  (change)="langSelected($event.value)" panelClass="panelResponsive">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let language of languages" [value]="language.value">
          <span>{{language.lang}}
            <span>
              <img src="{{language.img}}">
            </span>
          </span>
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
```

My languages array is:

```js
languages = [
    {
        'lang': '',
        'value': 'es-ES',
        'img': '/assets/images/languages/spainIco.png',
        'alt': 'SP'
    }, {
        'lang': '',
        'value': 'en-GB',
        'img': '/assets/images/languages/ukIco.png',
        'alt': 'UK'
    }
];
```

What I want to do is that if I choose spanish, the next time I open the dropdown, only appears the English option, and vice versa.

Thanks you all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, use a getter to filter the list of languages :

```js
get filteredLanguages() {
  return this.selectedLanguage ? 
    this.languages.filter(language => language.value !== this.selectedLanguage.value) : 
    this.languages;
}
```

```html
<mat-option *ngFor="let language of filteredLanguages" [value]="language.value">
```

Comment: yes but is only called when the page starts, when i change the option its not getting called the method

Comment: It should : by setting the value of your selected language, Angular triggers a change detection, meaning the value of the getter and the view are updated.

Comment: As you can see in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-grwgrm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts) it works as intended.

Comment: Above thing will work But selected value gets disappeared... That will be a problem.. Is that solving your purpose though?

Comment: @trichetriche look this [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-select2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) in angular material is like not working.

Comment: @Krishna the thing that trichetriche has done is what I want, but with angular material doesnt work. Im trying to workaround but I don't achieve anything

Comment: [This one](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-select2-gtocyw?file=src/app/app.component.html) works though.

Comment: @Arm144 use above example and when you are removing the element update the placeholder to the selected value. That may look more user friendly..

Comment: @trichetriche thanks a lot its work perfect now hundreds of thanks

Comment: @trichetriche
returning this, I am trying to show the selected value, I understand the code and I know how it works, but if I show the option selected, the filter does not work. Any clue to get to show the value once selected without having to change the placeholder value?

Answer (score 0):

You can hide mat-option by css property `display: none` . For that you can add specific class e.g. "d-none"

In html:

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let languageOption of languages" [value]="languageOption.value" [ngClass]="{'d-none': isAlreadySelectedLanguageOption(languageOption )}">
```

In ts:

```
isAlreadySelectedLanguageOption(languageOption): boolean {
    return this.form.languages.some((language) => language.value === languageOption.value);
}
```